# Help please with swatch patterns

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Please can anybody give me some easy instruction as to how to solve my problem with a diagonal line pattern swatch?  It seems to always offset the pattern when I try to use swatch a a fill [image][image]

Comment: Hi Karen. Welcome to GDSE. The "offsetting" problem you are seeing I think is only a GPU preview glitch.  Try zooming in, and it should go away. At least it does for me, or try switching to CPU preview instead, although that may give you other display glitches, such as gaps between the tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Starting with a path
  [image: Path]
- **Menu Object** > **Pattern** > **Make**

[image: Pattern]

- Select the Shape and fill it with the pattern

[image: FIll]

- Click the **Rotate Tool** twice to open the **Rotate Options window**
- Check only **Transform Patterns** and rotate

[image: Rotate]

[image: Animation]

Comment: I am in a real muddle now  - I have a font that I want to fill with these diagonal lines. attached screenshot.  Please can you talk me through it in simple steps? It is not a preview 'glitch' as other commentator suggests, because horizontal line pattern is fine.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: thanks, but I cant get past base 1 as soon as I create a line segment a pop up appears saying that a swatch has been added to the swatches panel and I have to edit! So then try your measurements and another pop up with option to fill line - it seems that CC keeps doing things automatically to create patterns.  Also the line is not expanded, so still a stroke. From what I have read it needs to be expanded to a fill? Still very muddled, sorry.

Comment: I cant get past base 1 as soon as I create a line segment a pop up appears saying that swatch added to  swatches panel have to edit! So then try your measurements and pop up with option to fill line - CC keeps automatically creating patterns. Line is not expanded, so still a stroke. Doesn't it need to be expanded to a fill? Still very muddled, sorry. what size line segment do you start with? Does it overlap the artboard or doesn't it matter if it is just one line?  Why your example of pattern show a grid of lines, +selection one line? - step by step for an idiot would be great!

Comment: Answer updated with animation

Comment: You are a STAR  Danielillo - this is so clear and seems to be working, thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking to ensure the *diagonal edges* of the `S` have a red stripe at them, then you can't really do that with patterns specifically.

Patterns adhere to their internal spacing and do *not* adjust based upon object edges. In other words, the pattern itself has no idea you've applied it to an `S` and you want it to span the edges of the glyph.

There are a couple things you can do though which might help. It's difficult to be precise without a complete picture of what the entire visual being created looks like, or should look like. It's fairly easy to offer suggestions for the `S`, but that does not mean what corrects the `S` works as well for other possible applications of the pattern.

- Scale the Pattern within the `S` if that's feasible. It may mean you need to scale the pattern *everywhere* it has been applied for visual consistency. You can reduce the pattern so that its tile size causes the red stripe to fall at the diagonal edges of the `S`. The problem here might be that although the pattern is corrected on the `S` it may be then incorrect on some other glyph when scaled.
- Reduce the spacing in the pattern itself. You could reduce the space between the stripes by editing the pattern swatch, until the red stripes fall where you want on the `S`. Typically adjusting the spacing between stripes slightly to accommodate this doesn't drastically alter the visual. But again, that may or may not cause spacing issues with the pattern elsewhere.